# Spring boot RabbitMQ Host string format

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-boot, spring-rabbit

I am using spring boot to listen for messages on my rabbitmq instance. I have it working locally using an `application.properties` file.

However, when I want to connect to the remote rabbit instance I am getting number format exceptions and unknown host exceptions because of my url.

I've tried setting `spring.rabbitmq.host` to:

`amqp://myurl/dev and myurl/dev and amqp%3A%2F%2Fmyurl%2Fdev`

Nothing is working. Any ideas what could be up. I have set my user name and pass for the remote instance as well.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Try removing the amqp:// part. The host property should just be that, the hostname:

```
spring.rabbitmq.host=myurl
```

Not sure what the /dev part is. Are you saying that is your virtual-host? If so then just set this property too:

```
spring.rabbitmq.virtual-host=dev
```

For username/password, set these properties:

```
spring.rabbitmq.username=
spring.rabbitmq.password=
```

Answer (score 0):

A better way to do this is to set

```
spring.rabbitmq.addresses=amqps://user:password@10.0.0.123/virtualhost
```

This will get auto-resolved, and correctly set your hostname, password etc

Github issue that fixes this:
https://github.com/spring-projects/spring-boot/issues/6401